# How to spawn multiple threads that call same function using std::thread C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

Basically what I would like to do is write a for loop that spawns multiple threads. The threads must call a certain function multiple times. So in other words I need each thread to call the same function on different objects. How can I do this using std::thread c++ library?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give some indication of what you've already tried.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply create threads in a loop, passing different arguments each time. In this example, they are stored in a `vector` so they can be joined later.

```
struct Foo {};

void bar(const Foo& f) { .... };

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    threads.push_back(std::thread(bar, Foo()));

  // do some other stuff

  // loop again to join the threads
  for (auto& t : threads)
    t.join();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a loop, each iteration constructing a separate thread object, all with the same function but different object as argument.

Comment: Why can't I use the same argument?

Comment: @tomtom1-4 If you define an object inside the loop, you are passing different objects ("different argument") to the threads. Even if the name of the object is the same inside the loop, the object itself will be created, copied (to the thread), and destructed each iteration of the loop. If you look at the example in [juanchopanza answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19675166/440558), you will see that each iteration he does `Foo()` to create an object, so while he pass "the same argument" it's in fact different objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use some of C++11 stuff as well as utilize great power of std::function + std::bind you could try something like this:

```
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

typedef std::function<void()> RunningFunction;

class MyRunner 
{
private:
    MyRunner(const MyRunner&);
    MyRunner& operator=(const MyRunner&);
    std::vector<std::thread> _threads;

public:

    MyRunner(uint32_t count, RunningFunction fn) : _threads()
    {
        _threads.reserve(count);
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            _threads.emplace_back(fn);
    }

    void Join()
    {
        for (std::thread& t : _threads)
            if (t.joinable())
                t.join();
    }
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<MyRunner> MyRunnerPtr;

class Foo
{
public:
    void Bar(uint32_t arg)
    {
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " arg = " << arg << std::endl;
    }
};


int calcArg()
{
    return rand() % UINT32_MAX;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<Foo> objs;

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
        objs.emplace_back(Foo());

    std::vector<MyRunnerPtr> runners;

    for (Foo& obj : objs)
    {
        const uint32_t someArg = calcArg();
        runners.emplace_back(std::make_shared<MyRunner>(1, std::bind(&Foo::Bar, &obj, someArg)));
    }

    for (MyRunnerPtr& runner : runners)
        runner->Join();
}
```